# what is /*-{ in my Java/GWT codebase

Tags: java, gwt

I'm going through a GWT project whic is already developed and I found a few methods in bellow pattern. Could some one expalin what is the meaning of /*- before and after curly brackets.

```
private static native int getAvailableScreenHeight() /*-{
    // Method body here
}-*/;
```

This is how it displays in Eclipse (Seems eclipse has identified it as valid method. when I pressed a space between * and - it shows as commented code)

[image]

Comment: Seems eclipse has identified it as valid method. when I pressed a space between * and - it shows as commented code

Comment: @laune I know java comments but this is a deference thing, check the chris martin's answer

Comment: The Q is much clearer now! (Header could have been formulated better.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a native Javascript method written using [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html). The GWT compiler uses it. The Java compiler ignores it.

Comment: ah, to the crux of the matter

Comment: Thanks you have understood my question well

Answer (score 0):

Is this method is declared in interface ? 
seems like it is prototype.

and any thing between /*any thing */ is ignored by compiler.
So your code is just like this

```
private static native int getAvailableScreenHeight();
```

Comment: Ignored by javac, but not by GWT.

Comment: Also, this isn't an interface. [Native methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.4) are declared in classes.